# A question about a proof of the Dirichlet test for uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I don't understand the proof of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). D:

For the Dirichlet test for uniform convergence, I saw a [proof in WikiProofs](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence). But I did not understand the proof, they say that all we need to show is that the other series converges uniformly; why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Dirichlet criterion states in detail:

> Let $a_k: D \to \mathbb{C}$ be functions for which there exists a constant $M$ such that for all $n$ and all $x \in D$ we have 
>   $$
> \left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x)\right| \leq M
> \tag{1}
> $$
>   and let $b_k: D \to [0,\infty)$ be functions that converge pointwise monotonically and uniformly to $0$, which means
>
> - for all $x\in D$ and all $k$ we have $$b_k (x) \geq b_{k+1}(x) \geq 0\tag{2}$$
> - for all $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there is $K$ such that for all $x \in D$ and all $k\geq K$ we have $$b_k(x) \lt \varepsilon. 
>   \tag{3}$$
>
> Then the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(x) b_k(x)$ converges uniformly on $D$.

The main idea of the proof is to use the so-called *Abel summation trick* or *[summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)*. To avoid need- and useless clutter in the formulas, let me drop the $x$ from the notation.

1. *Warm-up/preparation*

   Define $A_\ell = \sum_{k=1}^\ell a_k$ and note that $(1)$ tells us that
   $|A_\ell| \leq M$. Then $a_k = A_{k}-A_{k-1}$ and 
   $$
     \begin{align*}
       \sum_{k=1}^n \phantom{|} a_k b_k
      &= 
       A_1 b_1 + (A_2 - A_1)b_2 + \cdots + (A_n - A_{n-1})b_n \\
      & =
       A_1 (b_1 - b_2) + A_2 (b_2 - b_3) + \cdots + A_{n-1}(b_{n-1}-b_n) + A_n b_n \\
      & =
       \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \phantom{|} A_k\,(b_{k}-b_{k+1}) + A_n \,b_n.
     \end{align*}
     $$
   For $n \lt m$ we conclude from this and
   $\sum_{n+1}^m = \sum_{1}^m - \sum_{1}^n$ that 
   $$\tag{4}
       \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \phantom{|}a_k b_k =
       \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \phantom{|} A_k\,(b_{k}-b_{k+1}) + (A_m\,b_m - A_n\,b_n).
     $$
2. *Conclusion*

   Recall from $(1)$ that $|A_\ell| \leq M$ and from $(2)$ that 
   $b_k - b_{k+1} \geq 0$ as well as $b_m,b_n \geq 0$ so that the last equality
   $(4)$ lets us estimate
   $$
     \begin{align*}
       \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \phantom{|}a_k b_k\right| 
      &\leq
       \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \phantom{|} |A_k|\,(b_{k}-b_{k+1})
       + (|A_m|\,b_m  + |A_n|\,b_n) \\
      &\leq
       M \cdot \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \phantom{|}(b_{k}-b_{k+1}) + (M \,b_m + M \,b_n)
       = 2M \,b_n. 
     \end{align*}
     $$
   By $(3)$ there is for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ a $K$ such that for all
   $n \geq K$ we have $b_n \lt \varepsilon / 2M$ and thus we conclude for
   $m \gt n \geq K$ that 
   $$
     \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \phantom{|}a_k b_k\right|
     \leq 2M \,b_n \lt \varepsilon
     $$
   which tells us that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(x)\,b_k(x)$ converges
   uniformly on $D$ by the
   [Cauchy criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_criterion).

Notice that in essence we exploited the [telescoping property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) of the series $\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} (b_{k} - b_{k+1})$ in our penultimate estimate (which gives us its uniform convergence), as asserted on the [ProofWiki page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence) you linked to. However, phrasing it the way it is done there seems rather misleading to me, so I wouldn't have understood that proof either if I hadn't known about the Abel summation trick beforehand.

Comment: Excelent Answer!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that the sequence of partial sums 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S_N(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n(x) b_n(x)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
converges uniformly as $N \rightarrow \infty$.  Observe that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S_N(x) &=& \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n(x) b_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k(x)  \right) b_n(x) \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) b_n(x) - \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k(x) \right) b_n(x) \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) b_n(x) - \sum_{n=0}^{N+1} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k(x) \right) b_n(x) + \left( \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k(x) \right) b_{N+1}(x) \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) b_n(x) - \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k(x) \right) b_{n+1}(x) + \left( \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k(x) \right) b_{N+1}(x) \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) b_n(x) - \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k(x) \right) b_{n+1}(x) + \left( \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k(x) \right) b_{N+1}(x) \\ 
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) (b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x)) + \left( \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k(x) \right) b_{N+1}(x).
\end{eqnarray}
$$
(This manipulation is called partial summation or summation by parts.)
So it will be enough to show that both $\sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) (b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x))$ and $\left( \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k(x) \right) b_{N+1}(x)$ converge uniformly as $N \rightarrow \infty$

Since $\left( \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k(x) \right)$ is bounded and since $b_{n}(x)$ converges to $0$ uniformly, it follows that $\left( \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k(x) \right) b_{N+1}(x)$ converges to $0$ uniformly.

I leave it to you to show that the boundedness of $\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k(x) \right)$ and the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{N} |b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x)|$ implies that $\sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) (b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x))$ converges uniformly.

**Remark:** Instead of showing that $\sum_{n=0}^{N} |b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x)|$ converges uniformly using the Cauchy Criterion and then that the boundedness of $\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k(x) \right)$ and the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{N} |b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x)|$ implies that $\sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) (b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x))$ converges uniformly, I suggest just showing directly that $\sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \right) (b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x))$ converges uniformly using the Cauchy Criterion.  The argument is very similar to the one used to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{N} |b_n(x) - b_{n+1}(x)|$ converges uniformly.  Just add in the fact that $\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k(x) \right| \leq M$.

Comment: No, I refuse to observe *that*!